# How to run Gerrit on Windows with basic setup

Tags: windows, gerrit

I was trying to Google for answer and figure it out myself for few hours already but no success.
My idea is something like Gerrit's [Quick get started guide](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/install-quick.html) which unfortunately does not work under Windows.
I need it only for evaluation purposes, so H2 DB and other things like not working email, ... are not a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download gerrit

```
java -jar gerrit-full-2.5.2.war init
```

Follow the guide.

For testing purposes use development_become_any_account under authentication method.

then you will end up with a running server